# Deluge refuses every non-localhost connection despite remote connections being enabled

Tags: debian, iptables, bittorrent, sockets, deluge

I installed Deluge today on my Debian 8.0 VPS. Everything is working, except for remote connections. I explicitly enabled remote connections with `config -s allow_remote true` and after checking the JSON file it still is shown as true.

Despite this, it will refuse every connection not originating from loopback. The server is listed as offline in my remote client and a port checker return *Port closed*, while `netstat -npl` definetly shows that there is a socket listening on that port and `ps -p` that it is actually Deluge listening.

```
root@vps:~# netstat -npl
...
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58846         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/python
...
root@vps:~# ps -p 946
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  946 ?        00:00:19 deluged
```

It might be an issue with `iptables`, but I am neither familiar with it nor did I ever change anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here in your post

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58846         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/python
                    /\
```

you are only listening on `127.0.0.1`, you will have a configuration file somewhere, for your *deluged* application, that specifies which IP addresses to bind to.

If you were properly listening on all interfaces, it would look something like this

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58846         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/python
```

**edit**

Looking at [some documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Deluge#Allow_remote), you might also need to set

```
"allow_remote": true
```

In your `$HOME/.config/deluge/core.conf` file.

After making this change, try restarting the service, and see if that fixes the bind.

Comment: I noticed the oddity in netstat, that was the exact reason I asked here. I tried all of that and I can confirm that the values are `"allow_remote": true` and `listen_interface: "0.0.0.0"` in the config file located in the deluge users home. After confirming this I restarted the service and looked again, to no avail.

Comment: Checking again the issue seemed to be a broken service. I started it manually and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.  I ended up changing core.conf, as follows, to resolve the issue...

"listen_interface": "", 
   "allow_remote": true,

Comment: Done exactly that. Didn't help. Any other ideas?